# When changing the href attribute of a link using jQuery, how do I reference the current href attribute?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the href attribute of links on my page. I need the bulk of the url to remain the same but just change a parameter. I've got this so far:

```
$("a[href*='/new_note?']").attr('href', function() {
    return this.replace(/date1=[\d-]+/, "date1=" + $("[name='new_date1']").val());
});
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
this.replace is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the second parameter of the function you're passing into [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), like this:

```
$("a[href*='/new_note?']").attr('href', function(i, oldHref) {
    return oldHref.replace(/date1=[\d-]+/, "date1=" + $("[name='new_date1']").val());
});
```

For this function:

- `this` - The current DOM element
- `i` (First Parameter) - The index of the element in the set
- `oldHref` (Second Parameter) - The *current* value of the attribute

---

A side suggestion here, *just* a `[name='new_date1']` [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) is quite expensive, if you know the element type add it on to make it *much* faster, for example:

```
$("input[name='new_date1']").val()
```

Then to make it even faster, fetch the value once before this [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function (which runs for *every* element), so you're only fetching that value once, like this:

```
var newDate = $("input[name='new_date1']").val();
$("a[href*='/new_note?']").attr('href', function(i, oldHref) {
  return oldHref.replace(/date1=[\d-]+/, "date1=" + newDate);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for not only answering the question, but taking the time to explain the other stuff!